# Were families allowed to watch boys swim naked at the YMCA before the 70s?

Tags: united-states, sports

[image]
*from [Minneapolis Tribune, 1950](https://a79a32a7-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/historicarchives4maleswimming/home/archives---mid-20th-century-to-current/photographs/Minneapolis%20Tribune%20-%201950.jpg?attachauth=ANoY7covmdY9PYQvoV8Rlq_IdQF2JmRadSdR4YbWYUgfVyEtRtB97jaCrdbJSwjWPuB2Zqi4TVaMI2KN4W6gSFVwHdDLrN7m13V-VIrVjipAeKKKxqMitFLWuEmSyvzm8y0UvFMG6VE2AyNg5FCu1v70Rw-8-002mVLgMEUim4A6bM250fCkjRzZpDfCeXXd1SBZFo1NS2R_bz8hjOBCG3l_LbxVpi-OcaoJiBLReQ3JprwaN0ekV_fAyYz1479NPyG51_5PWxqgz0H-PKc6TeJWlK9Q__9Am7jR2XnT4oXrlpsTLIutgPC0KBcXMGGYmu1CaiUdPFliSZNAE3bNm_NFdbVi5ns3MQ%3D%3D&attredirects=0) as cited in [Medium](https://medium.com/@Robbie.Mukai/swim-class-for-american-high-schoolers-was-required-naked-bebbc4a5ded7)*

And does "families" mean female siblings would have been allowed to watch or was it just the parents?

I found [American High Schools Mandated Naked Swimming](https://medium.com/@Robbie.Mukai/swim-class-for-american-high-schoolers-was-required-naked-bebbc4a5ded7) on
Medium.com

Comment: This [Quora question](https://www.quora.com/What-was-the-reason-why-boys-were-not-allowed-to-wear-swimsuits-at-the-YMCA-in-the-60s-and-70s) has several answers from people relating their personal experiences in the 60s & 70s. One reason why swimsuits weren't allowed appears to have been hygiene. Also, several answers claim that nudity of young boys was not a big deal back then.

Comment: Of related interest is this [Seattle YMCA Apologizes for Bathing Suit Ban](https://www.parentmap.com/article/seattle-ymca-bathing-suit-ban). How times change...

Comment: @axsvl77 Hi. I updated the question and added the site I found it on.

Comment: Is that link to the Tribune paper working for anyone? (It's also ridiculously long) Please fix it up so that it can be accessed…

Comment: @LаngLаngС I couldn't get it to work, but the article on medium was a good start.

Comment: @LarsBosteen it does have to do with hygiene. Fibre from swimwear would clog up the filters, and because bacteria and fungi can easily multiply in dirty swimwear. Better filtration systems and things like chlorine and ozone treatment of the water have changed that. And yes, people were a lot less prudish at the time than they are now (heck, where I live there are calls to ban bikinis as "immoral").